# Encrypting and Decrypting Isolated Storage File

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, encryption, isolatedstorage

I want to encrypt and decrypt the isolated storage file.

The Microsoft site took me [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

1. While using Isolated Storage on the emulator, it can persist only until the emulator is running.
2. There is no way to get the physical location of the Isolated Storage.

I hope the above statements of mine are correct.

Now, I want to know how can I encrypt the Isolated Storage file ?

Taking the example provided by Microsoft,  (application name is GasMileage)

here is the code

```
namespace CodeBadger.GasMileage.Persistence
{
    public class IsolatedStorageGateway
    {
        private const string StorageFile = "data.txt";
        private readonly XmlSerializer _serializer;

    public IsolatedStorageGateway()
    {
        _serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Notebook));
    }

    public Notebook LoadNotebook()
    {
        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (var stream = GetStorageStreamForReading(store))
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                return reader.EndOfStream 
                    ? new Notebook() 
                    : (Notebook) _serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }
    }

    public NotebookEntry LoadEntry(Guid guid)
    {
        var notebook = LoadNotebook();
        return notebook.Where(x => x.Id == guid).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public void StoreEntry(NotebookEntry entry)
    {
        var notebook = LoadNotebook();
        AssignId(entry);
        RemoveExistingEntryFromNotebook(notebook, entry);
        Console.WriteLine(entry);
        notebook.Add(entry);
        WriteNotebookToStorage(notebook);
    }

    public void DeleteEntry(NotebookEntry entry)
    {
        var notebook = LoadNotebook();
        RemoveExistingEntryFromNotebook(notebook, entry);
        WriteNotebookToStorage(notebook);
    }

    private void WriteNotebookToStorage(Notebook notebook)
    {
        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        using (var stream = GetStorageStreamForWriting(store))
        {
            _serializer.Serialize(stream, notebook);
        }
    }

    private static void AssignId(NotebookEntry entry)
    {
        if (entry.Id == Guid.Empty) entry.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    private static void RemoveExistingEntryFromNotebook(Notebook notebook, NotebookEntry entry)
    {
        var toRemove = notebook.Where(x => x.Id == entry.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        if (toRemove == null) return;
        notebook.Remove(toRemove);
    }

    private static IsolatedStorageFileStream GetStorageStreamForWriting(IsolatedStorageFile store)
    {
        return new IsolatedStorageFileStream(StorageFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, store);
    }

    private static IsolatedStorageFileStream GetStorageStreamForReading(IsolatedStorageFile store)
    {
        return new IsolatedStorageFileStream(StorageFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read, store);
    }
}
```

Now I want to know, How to encrypt the **data.txt** given in the context.

On Application load, decrypt the file and on application termination, it should encrypt.

Can someone help me on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ProtectedData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata%28v=vs.96%29.aspx) class will encrypt/decrypt a byte array for storing on isolated storage. You can supply your own additional entropy, but by default:

> In Silverlight for Windows Phone, both the user and machine credentials are used to encrypt or decrypt data

For more information, see [How to: Encrypt Data in a Windows Phone Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh487164%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @Richard . I am aware of the DPAPI which can encrypt and decrypt confidential data such as passwords, connection strings, and PINs. I wanted to know, if there is something to encrypt the decrypt the entire isolated storage file itself. For example a text file with data into unreadable form.

Comment: Once the data has been encrypted using the DPAPI, you would write the data to the text file. When loading the text file, you would load it into a byte array and then decrypt it before reading the text.